# how do I access a parent attribute of a selected line item in a jquery ui menu

Tags: jquery-ui, parent-child, menuitem

On my html page, I have multiple menus. When a line item is clicked, I want to get the id attribute of the parent anchor tag from the menu where the selection originates. My html and jquery code is below.

```
//HTML

<ul id="menuA">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="ageGroup" class="age">Age Group</a>
            <ul>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">18-21</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">21-30</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">30-40</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">40-50</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">50-60</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">60-70</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">70-80</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">80-90</a></li>
                <li name="ageGroup"><a href="#">90-100</a></li>
            </ul>

    </li>
    </ul>

//JQUERY

$(function(){

    $('#menuA').menu({ 

select: function(event, ui){

      var choice = ui.item.text(); //get text of menu selection

    //here is where I want to get the id attribute of the anchor tag. What I have isn't working. id is coming up undefined.

    var id = ui.item.parents('a').attr('id'); 


     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the corresponding tag id by using:

```
var id = ui.item.parents('li').find('a').attr('id');
```

Your previous attempt didn't work as parent selector was returning your list items () instead of searching for a tag in the main li.